# Strategy in auction game given asymmetric information

Tags: probability, game-theory, auction-theory

Suppose that 100 coins are flipped, and for every head \$1 enters a bucket. You and a friend are bidding on the bucket in a first price sealed bid auction, where bids are limited to integer values (and ties are solved uniformly). It is straightforward to see that the optimal strategy for both players is to bid \$49 (both players have an expected payoff of \$0.50.

Now suppose your opponent can see the result of the first 10 coin flips. Clearly they will now bid $\$(45+n)$, where $n$ is the number of heads they saw in the first 10 flips. What is your optimal strategy however? Should you still bid \$49? And how does the expected value change?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  Are you told your opponents bid?  Or do you simply know that they have a huge advantage? In the latter case, bidding a low number seems wise.

Comment: @lulu It is a first price sealed bid auction, meaning that you both submit a bid simultaneously (without knowing each others bids), and the higher bid buys the bucket for that price.

Comment: So you are asked to bid in a massively unfair game?  I assume the optimal response is to pass, or at least close to that.  Your only winning scenario is to outbid the player with better information and then get lucky as to the outcome.  Not a great strategy.  Might be hard to write it out though, since of course their optimal bid depends on yours.

Comment: More thoughtfully:  if you knew they saw $0$ you'd bid $45$ or maybe $44$.  So you should at least bid that.  That would lead to them bidding $1$ more than you  if they actually saw some Heads, so maybe (since they almost certainly saw some Heads) you could bump your bid up a bit.  Don't think I'd go as high as $49$ though, since then you only win the pot if they saw few Heads.  So now you just have to check the few values in between.